# ¿Cómo llamar una función dentro de otra en Python y usar el resultado de la primera en la segunda?

Tags: python, python-3.8

Tengo estas funciones...

```py
def start():
    w0=[]
    e3=[[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,0],[1,0,1],
         [1,1,0],[1,1,1]]
    for i in range (3):
        w0.append(random.uniform(-2,2))
    print("El primer vector de pesos es: ",w0)
    t=0
    X=random.choice(e3)
    print("El vector X a utilizar es: ",X)
    test()
```

```py
def test():
    N=[[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,0],[1,0,1],
         [1,1,0]]
    P=[[1,1,1]]
    X=[]
    w0=[]
    pp=sum(list(map(operator.mul,X,w0)))
    print("El producto punto de X y W es: ",pp)
    return(pp)
    if X in P and pp>0:
        print("El vector ",X," esta en P y Go to Test")
    elif X in P and pp<=0:
        print("Go to Add")
        add()
    elif X in N and pp<0:
        print("El vector ",X," esta en N")
    elif X in N and pp>=0:
        print("Go to Subtract")
        subtract()
```

y tengo otras dos funciones, una que se llama `add()` y otra `subtract()`.
Mi pregunta es ¿cómo puedo hacer para que la función `start()` llame a la función `test()` y que `test` haga lo que tiene que hacer con los valores que `start` genera?
Espero haberme hecho a entender, ya que como tengo mi código, no funciona. Manda un cero cuando no debe mandar cero.

Comment: Hola. Lo que quieres hacer se puede hacer haciendo una clase y dentro insertando  cuyas funciones

Answer (score 0):

@Paloma,

Para poder ocupar una función dentro de otra función lo que debes hacer es una instancia del objeto, en el siguiente ejemplo puedes ver como se ocupa el resultado de la función add() dentro de la función sub() y luego ambos resultados en una ultima función llamada results(). La cual imprime el valor final de cada variable después de su transformación al ejecutarse cada uno de los métodos.

```
x = 10
y = 5
c = 0
total = 0

def add ():
    total = x + y
    return total

def sub ():
    a = add()
    c = a - y
    total = c
    return total    

def results():
    a = add()
    b = sub()
    total = a * b

    print( "El total de la primera función (add) es:", a )
    print( "El total de la segunda función (sub) es:", b )
    print( "El total de la tercera función (results) es:", total)
    print( "Fin de la ejecución" )

results()
```

Entonces la última función results() imprime el valor del resultado de las primeras 2 funciones y luego ocupa el resultado de la función add() y sub() para realizar una multiplicación en la función results().

```
total = a * b #Que es igual a 150 en este ejemplo.
```

Puedes encontrar más información sobre las clases, objetos e instancias en la documentación oficial de python en el siguiente link:

> https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Saludos

Comment: No veo ningún objeto ni instancia en tu ejemplo de código. Lo que usas en cambio son variables globales (que no son aconsejables). Sin OOP puede hacerse también pasando como parámetros a las funciones lo que éstas necesiten, en vez de usar variables globales.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que estás intentando preguntar es cómo se pasan parámetros a las funciones.

Ya que quieres que la función `test()` pueda trabajar con datos que no genera ella misma sino que "le llegan desde fuera", lo que necesitas es que la función reciba esos datos "externos" como parámetros.

En tu caso lo primero que habría que aclarar es cuáles de las variables que creas en `test()` necesitas que vengan "de fuera". A priori sospecho que se trata de la variable `N`, pues le asignas los mismos datos que la función `start()` pone en `e3`. Por otro lado veo que también usa una variable `X` y otra `w0`, las cuales tambíen existen en `start()`. Voy a suponer que también quieres "transmitir" esas variables entre funciones.

En ese caso lo que tienes que hacer es reescribir `test()` de modo que declare tres parámeros (`N`, `X`, y `w0`) y entonces no asigne nada a esas variables en su interior, sino que las use sin más, suponiendo que "desde fuera" alguien les asignará un valor al llamar. Quedaría así:

```
def test(N, X, w0):
    P=[[1,1,1]]
    pp=sum(list(map(operator.mul,X,w0)))
    print("El producto punto de X y W es: ",pp)
    return(pp)                      # <--- Este return no sobraría?
    if X in P and pp>0:
        print("El vector ",X," esta en P y Go to Test")
    elif X in P and pp<=0:
        print("Go to Add")
        add()
    elif X in N and pp<0:
        print("El vector ",X," esta en N")
    elif X in N and pp>=0:
        print("Go to Subtract")
        subtract()
```

Entonces, desde la otra función, cuando invoques `test()` le pasas como parámetros las variables que quieras asignar a los argumentos. Puedes hacerlo basándote simplemente en su posición (por ejemplo `test(a, b, c)` asignaría `a` al argumento `N`, `b` al argumento `X` y `c` al argumento `w0`) o ser más explícito y usar nombres, como en: `test(N=a, X=b, w0=c)`.

Usando esta técnica, `start()` quedaría así:

```
def start():
    w0=[]
    e3=[[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,0],[1,0,1],
         [1,1,0],[1,1,1]]
    for i in range (3):
        w0.append(random.uniform(-2,2))
    print("El primer vector de pesos es: ",w0)
    t=0
    X=random.choice(e3)
    print("El vector X a utilizar es: ",X)
    test(N=e3, X=X, w0=w0)
```

Tu pregunta menciona también "usar el resultado de la primera en la segunda", pero no sé si te estás refiriendo a lo que acabo de mostrar (preparar unos datos en `start()` y pasarlos como parámetro a `test()`) o si lo que quieres es que los resultados calculados por `test()` estén disponibles en `start()`. Si es lo segundo, debes usar `return` en `test()` para retornar lo que necesites, y en `start()` recogerás ese resultado en otra variable, por ejemplo:

```
def start():
   ...
   resultado = test(N=e3, X=X, w0=w0)
```